# Looking for ways to optimize multi poly-lines on canvas in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm working on program in WPF that need to plot on one of her screens 50 poly-lines that describes movement of some energy in space. One more demand from the program is to move two lines and a dot to indicate the mouse location when its relevant.

The problem is that when the poly-lines cover a high percent of the canvas and the mouse is fly over the canvas then all start to run really slowly.
I succeeded to improve this a little but its still not good enough so I'm asking for your help please.

So because this canvas related to another one, I spited the work for two - the handler and the movement function:

```
private void rayTraceCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Point pos = e.GetPosition(rayTraceCanvas);
    mouseMove(pos);

    if (m_MouseMoveCallback != null)
        m_MouseMoveCallback(m_CurrentDepth);
 }
```

And then the movement function:

```
private void mouseMove(Point currentPos)
{
    m_CurrentDepth = Math.Round((currentPos.Y) / (m_PixelPerDepthUnit));
    m_CurrentRange = Math.Round((currentPos.X) / (m_PixelPerRangeUnit));

    DepthPos.Text = "D: " + m_CurrentDepth.ToString();
    RangePos.Text = "R: " + m_CurrentRange.ToString();

    rayTraceWidthLine.Y1 = currentPos.Y;
    rayTraceWidthLine.Y2 = currentPos.Y;


    rayTraceHeightLine.X1 = currentPos.X;
    rayTraceHeightLine.X2 = currentPos.X;

    Canvas.SetLeft(rayTraceDotOnGraph, currentPos.X - (rayTraceDotOnGraph.Width / 2));
    Canvas.SetTop(rayTraceDotOnGraph, currentPos.Y - (rayTraceDotOnGraph.Height / 2));
}
```

I tried this without the deleget from the handler function and its work the same so the problem isn't there.

Comment: If you want better performances you can override the OnRender function and draw lines yourself using DrawingContext.DrawGeometry on a PathGeometry (containing a PathFigure)

Comment: I'd also recommend to put the cursor lines in a different layer, e.g. another Canvas on top of the other.